# How to check if a string contains a specific format

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to see if the string contains a specific format. For example if someone types a phone number 1234567890 I need to force a person to enter a phone number in a specific format. 
(###) ###-####. I am make changes to a vended program where the design of the program is terrible where you cannot force the formatting within a form. So, I was wondering if there is a way to use string.contains("(###) ###-####") or any other help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this winforms, webforms, WPF, or ???

Comment: Use a RegularExpression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sounds like you want to use regular expressions (aka Regex) Regex is usually the best route to go when trying to get or check strings against a pattern.

[here is MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) and [here is a decent how-to on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx)

a [quick google](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=.net%20Regex) will show you tons and tons of examples,tutorials, and libraries of expressions

Comment: Yeah that actually makes sense :). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx)

Comment: +1 - And if this is ASP.NET istead of webforms, there is a simnilar control on the Ajax Control Toolkit and I'm sure there are others as well...

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx). Basically you have to come up with a regexp and then use e.g. the IsMatch method to check whether the user input matches. If not then the phone number is in the wrong format.

Here is a sample

```
        // Matches (123) 123-1234 or (123) 123 1234
        var pattern = @"\((?<AreaCode>\d{3})\)\s*(?<Number>\d{3}(?:-|\s*)\d{4})";
        var regexp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);
        var userInput = "(123) 555-1243";
        if (!regexp.IsMatch(userInput))
        {
            // Does not match. User input is in incorrect format
            return;
        }
```

For learning purposes I would suggest you use a software such as the [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) or google for regular expression phone number. The expression I used in the sample comes with the Expresso (free tool).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use Regular Expressions?

[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are many options but the safest is to use the Regex class and match the string with the desired expressions (see some samples [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/validate-phone-number))

Answer (score 0):

why not create a method where you can control the format on the field for example if they leave the field and type 12345671454 pass that into this method and return the formatted string

```
   public static string FormatNumberPhone(string inputString)
   {
       string tempString;
       tempString = string.Format("{0:(###)###-####}", Convert.ToInt32(inputString));
       return tempString;
   }
```